# How to print values of a 3 dimensional array that are less than a specific value?

Tags: python, loops, indexing

so I have a dataset named data_low that looks like this:

```
(array([ 0,  0,  0, ..., 30, 30, 30]), array([  2,   2,   5, ..., 199, 199, 199]), array([113, 114,  64, ...,  93,  94,  96]))
```

And this is its shape: (84243,3).

I can get a unique value for precipitation from the dataset like this:

```
In [63]: print(data_low[0, 2, 113])
Out [63]: 1.74
```

What I am trying to do is print all the values in my dataset that have a value of less than 3.86667. I'm pretty new to python, and don't really know which loop to use in order to this. Help is much appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: Here is the program I currently have. For some context, I used ncecat to combine 31 datasets, so that is why I have three 1D arrays: the first array is the day, and the 2nd and 3rd represent longitude and latitude.

```
data_path = r"C:\Users\matth\Downloads\TRMM_3B42RT\3B42RT_Daily.201001.7.nc4"
f = Dataset(data_path)

latbounds = [ -38 , -20 ]
lonbounds = [ 115 , 145 ] # degrees east ? 
lats = f.variables['lat'][:] 
lons = f.variables['lon'][:]

# latitude lower and upper index
latli = np.argmin( np.abs( lats - latbounds[0] ) )
latui = np.argmin( np.abs( lats - latbounds[1] ) ) 

# longitude lower and upper index
lonli = np.argmin( np.abs( lons - lonbounds[0] ) )
lonui = np.argmin( np.abs( lons - lonbounds[1] ) )

precip_subset = f.variables['precipitation'][ : , lonli:lonui , latli:latui ]

print(precip_subset.shape)
print(precip_subset.size)
print(np.mean(precip_subset))

data_low = np.nonzero((precip_subset > 0) & (precip_subset < 3.86667))
print(data_low)

x = list(zip(*data_low))[:]
xx = np.array(x)
print(xx.shape)
print(xx.size)

for i in range(0,84243,1):
    print(data_low[i, i, i])
```

OUT:

```
In [136]: %run "C:\Users\matth\precip_anomalies.py"
(31, 120, 72)
267840
1.51398
(array([ 0,  0,  0, ..., 30, 30, 30]), array([  7,   7,   7, ..., 119, 119, 
119]), array([ 9, 10, 11, ..., 23, 53, 54]))
(13982, 3)
41946
[ 0  0  0 ..., 30 30 30]

TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\matth\precip_anomalies.py in <module>()
     53 
     54 for i in range(0,84243,1):
---> 55     print(data_low[i, i, i])

TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Comment: This does not look like an array with shape `84243x3`, but like a three_tuple with three 1d arrays.

Comment: How do you want to print them? Just in a long list, or their indices, or the remaining cells somehow "blanked out"?

Comment: i used list(zip(*data_low))[:] and then created it into a numpy array. after that i found the size and it was (84243, 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `data_low` is a numpy matrix (based on your question it is not, it is a 3-tuple with three arrays), you can use masking:

```
data_low[data_low < 3.86667]
```

This will return a 1D numpy array that contains all the values that are less than 3.86667.

If you want these as a vanilla Python list, you can use:

```
list(data_low[data_low < 3.86667])
```

But if you want to do further processing (in numpy) you better use the numpy array anyway.

Comment: I was thinking of doing something like "for i in range (0, 84243, 1):
print(data_low[ [i], [i], [i] ]), but I keep getting an error saying i need integer values

Comment: Why do you write it with `[i]`, and not `i` (like `print(data_low[i,i,i])`)? Furthermore you better try to minimize the number of calls at Python level, since numpy is more efficient.

Comment: when i do it like that, it gives me an error: "tuple indices must be integers, not tuple"

Comment: @MatthewKim: can you update your question with a program that reproduces the error?

Comment: I posted it above

Comment: Is there something I should change in my code prior to the loop?

Comment: @MatthewKim: but why do you use `np.nonzero`, etc. Please first state what you exactly want to do. It looks like if you make things far too complicated.

Comment: data_low has all the values in precip_subset that are greater than 0 and less than 3.86667. From there, I want to list the actual values of data_low, which I was trying to do through 'print(data_low[i, i, i])'

Comment: @MatthewKim: but why don't you simply set `data_low = precip_subset[(precip_subset > 0) & (precip_subset < 3.86667)]` and then `for val in data_low: print(val)`?

Comment: You are right, i made it WAY too complicated. Thank you for your time.